# Restrict access to a page when event fires

Tags: laravel

i have created a booking system which synchronizes with Google Calendar every 5 minutes and also truncates and old data and fetches new one from calendar, this process takes about 2-3 seconds.

What i want to do is, when the event to fetch data from Google Calendar fires, i want to disable access to the route of the booking system for these 2-3 seconds then enable it again when the event ends, i want to do this because it truncates the old data and fetches new one, so if a person is looking at the booking system this 2-3 seconds all the book schedule times will be free and i don't want this to happen.

Is this kind of thing possible?
Thanks and regards!

Comment: How do you sync with Google Calendar? You could achieve your goal by synchronizing with Google with server side instead of Ajax. Since you can handle both syncronizing and routes, you could do what you want.

Comment: The synchronization takes place in server side, i just want to find out how to disable access to a route inside an event/controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, my suggestion is to create a new field in your users table something like : is_google_sync_active and route middleware.

Then just before you will start sync. you change that field to true and in your new middleware you may check whether your sync. is active or not, then when your sync. ends you just change the value of field again to false. So, every time when user tries to pass to your sync route he will be passing your middleware which wil handle all job.

In addition, you can redirect user to page which shows status or progress if the sync. is processing.